Extend image with blurred frame using ImageMagick?
I'd like to make certain images larger by adding a blurred frame (consisting of the image itself). Would like to do that using ImageMagick.
Sort of like what https://pinetools.com/blurred-frame-images-generator does.


How to do that?
Searched Google for hints, but didn't really find something…
Found Blur image with ImageMagick and extent it and this command:
convert original.png -background none -gravity center -extent 200x200% -blur ... -trim result.png

But I guess I'm doing something wrong. When I run that command, the result.png looks identical to "original.png".


Something along these lines maybe?

open the image
in some "aside-processing" clone the original, enlarge and blur it
back in the mainline processing, put the enlarged, blurred image to the back of the depth stacking order, and composite the original over the blurred one with aligned centres


magick tour.jpg \( +clone -resize 150% -blur x10 \) +swap -gravity center -composite  result.jpg



For my money, I'd darken the background a little too in order to make it less distracting:
magick tour.jpg \( +clone -resize 150% -blur x20 -fill black -colorize 25% \) +swap -gravity center -composite  result.jpg



Awesome! That's exactly what I was looking for. I also very much liked how you made it a bit darker in the 2nd example.
